# Ionic / Angular.js Global Preloader

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am new to angular and ionic. Basically spent about 2 hours on this.

Wondering if someone can point me in the right direction here.

Basically in my controller.js I am loading remote json via $http.

I want to show a preloader on each controller that loads remote content.

```
    .controller('InformationCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $ionicLoading) {
    $scope.show = function () {
        $ionicLoading.show({
            template: '<p>Loading...</p><ion-spinner></ion-spinner>'
        });
    };
    $scope.hide = function () {
        $ionicLoading.hide();
    };
    $scope.show($ionicLoading);
    $http.get($scope.base_url + "information")
        .then(function (response) {
            $scope.hide($ionicLoading);
            $scope.information = response.data;
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            $scope.hide($ionicLoading);
            alert("error loading content");
        });
})
```

I am wondering, is there not an easier way to just create a global function preloaderShow() and preloaderHide() ? Seems like a lot of code to have to include the below in each controller and what if I want to modify the spinner later on, I have to update each line of code?

```
    .controller('InformationCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $ionicLoading) {
    $scope.show = function () {
        $ionicLoading.show({
            template: '<p>Loading...</p><ion-spinner></ion-spinner>'
        });
    };
    $scope.hide = function () {
        $ionicLoading.hide();
    };
```

I just used the starter app so maybe I am missing something, I saw something on using Services, any quick example or suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily abstract it to a service

```
angular.module('app').factory('loader', function loaderFactory ($ionicLoading) {
  return {
    show: function () {
      $ionicLoading.show({
        template: '<p>Loading...</p><ion-spinner></ion-spinner>'
      });
    },
    hide: function () {
      $ionicLoading.hide();
    };
  }  
});
```

then in you controller

```
angular.module('app').controller('InformationCtrl', function ($scope, $http, loader) {
  loader.show();
  $http.get($scope.base_url + "information")
  .then(function (response) {
    $scope.information = response.data;
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    alert("error loading content");
  })
  .finally(function () {
    loader.hide();
  });
}
```